# iOS as BLE peripheral - connection issue

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, connection

Have anybody experiences with Bluetooth Smart development to iOS? I need to use iDevice as BLE advertising peripheral according to GAP layer specification. I use [LightBlue](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lightblue-bluetooth-low-energy/id557428110?mt=8) for switching to peripheral role. Central device is based on Texas Instruments solution based on CC2541 wireless mcu. My issue is following:

- Central discover advertising iDevice
- connect it
- after circa 10 seconds iDevice send event about **disconnect**.

Session is established with **connection parameters** according to [Apple Bluetooth LE guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/hardwaredrivers/BluetoothDesignGuidelines.pdf):

- maximum connection interval: 100ms
- minimum connection interval: 100ms
- connection timeout: 3100ms
- slave latency: 0

Could anyone with experiences help? It is very important for me.

Thank you for any help,

Martin Petrik

Answer (score 0):

Martin,

If you just connect to the iDevice it will disconnect from you. You have to discover services and/or configure a service, pairing might work too. The iDevice won't allow you to connect and "do nothing", it will disconnect after several seconds. Since you are using a TI radio and I'm assuming a TI stack, I recommend using the TI E2E forums for any further questions.